# NodeJS app crashing on Heroku with error "Stopping process with SIGKILL"

Tags: node.js, heroku

The code shown below fails on Heroku with the error `Stopping process with SIGKILL`

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  var server_port = process.env.YOUR_PORT || process.env.PORT || 80;
  var server_host = process.env.YOUR_HOST || '0.0.0.0';
  server.listen(server_port, server_host, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server_port);
  });
});
```

Logs:

```
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared the variable `server`.

You can do:

```
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  //your stuff
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 80");
});
```